# Invalid toolchain. New Apps and Apps updates must be compiled with public versions

Tags: version, beta, toolchain

When I've tried to sent my app for apple analysis, on iTunesConnect, I've received the following message: "Invalid toolchain. New Apps and Apps updates must be compiled with public versions (GM) of 6 or later and Xcode iOS SDK 8 or later. Do not send apps compiled with beta software."  But my version XCode 7 is public, downloaded from the apple site. How can I fix this?

Comment: My mistake. The version of my OSX was Beta :).  Problem solved!